# Output image(chart) to browser

Tags: php, html

I'm currently trying to output an image (chart generated with PHP).
After I get all the data I need I just output the image to disk with:

```
imagepng($img, "img/graf.png", 0);
imagedestroy($img);
```

Then I call the image on the page, but the browser uses always the cached image instead of the newly generated image.
So I am trying to output the image to browser.

Main page is **k_b.php**.
The graph is generated, when I call the file **grafico.php** with an

```
include 'grafico.php';
```

present in k_b.php file.
Then I have some code that shows diferent buttons/text depending on other factors, but I must show that chart.

When I try to output the chart directly to the browser I just shows the chart and nothing else. with `imagepng($img);`

EDIT:
Found this online and it seems to work;

```
ob_start();
imagepng($img);
$contents =  ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$imagem = "<img src='data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode($contents)."' />";
imagedestroy($img);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try again just saving the image to disk and using a normal HML `<img>` tag to point to it, adding a query string which is different each time should prevent the browser from showing a cached version.

```
<img src="img/graph.png?<?= time() ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If the script with `imagepng($img);` sends the image to the browser you can use

```
<img src="grafico.php" alt="" />
```

to get the image in a html file.

Comment: That should work, what is in grafico.php ? I think appropriate header is missing.